# How to properly broadcast array indexing for NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

**Short description:**

I have two numpy arrays.

- `data`, `data.shape` is a tuple with X entries
- `indices`,`indices.shape` is the tuple `(X,Y)`

`indices` is basically a list of index arrays.
The arrays along the second dimension specify lists of indices for the corresponding dimension in `data`.

- `indices[0,:]` is a list of indices for the first dimension of `data`.
- `indices[1,:]` is a list of indices for the second dimension of `data`.

I would like to have a combination of all of them, an outer product.

The syntax I would like to use is simply:

```
data[indices]
```

**EDIT:**

Here was a long step-by-step review of all the things I tried, now obsolete
I found the solution, it's below.

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution.
In my answer below, there's an explanation how this indexing works.
You probably want to use Divakar's version though, he shows the `np.ix()` command which does exactly what is needed in one call.

Comment: @downvoter, could you at least comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) for creating such broadcastable indexing arrays, which could then be directly used for indexing. Thus, with `indices` as an array of shape `(M, N)`, where `N` would represent the number of dimension in the data array, we would have an implementation that works on ndarrays of any number of dimensions, like so -

```
data[np.ix_(*indices.T)]
```

If `indices` is of shape `(N, M)`, where `N` represents the number of dimension in the data array, skip the transpose : `data[np.ix_(*indices)]`.

Comment: beautiful, it's the same code I posted below but in one handy command. Thank you very much

Comment: I just tried your code. I think the transposing of the indices is wrong. indices has the shape (X,Y) where X is the number of dimensions of data. In my test transposing indices led to an error "too many indices for array"

Comment: @lhk As stated in the post : `"... with indices as an array of shape (M, N), where N would represent the number of dimension in the data array"`. If the indices is the other way as in your case : `"shape (X,Y) where X is the number of dimensions of data"'`, then don't transpose and just use : `data[np.ix_(*indices)]`. Updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to select items from a `data` array is by using tuples.

You need to create a tuple, where the items of the tuple are lists of indices. But there is a trick: The lists will be zipped together and this zipping broadcasts the lists.

Take this tuple for example:

```
( [0,1], [0,1] )
```

will take the elements `[0,0]` and `[1,1]`.

You can try to use commands like `np.tile` or `np.repeat`, to match the correct indices with each other. I tried and it's very complicated to get that right.

There's an easier way:

```
indices=np.arange(10)

data=np.random.randn(10,10,10)

x_list=indices
y_list=indices
z_list=indices

# this will broadcast the lists together
# the shapes (10,) , (10, ) and (10, ) result in the shape (10, )
data[(x_list, y_list, z_list)].shape    # (10,)

#now the trick
x_list=x_list.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
y_list=y_list.reshape((1, -1, 1))
z_list=z_list.reshape((1, 1, -1))

# this will do broadcasting, too
# but now the shapes are (10, 1, 1), (1, 10, 1) and (1, 1, 10)
data[(x_list, y_list, z_list)].shape # (10, 10, 10)
```