# Broadcasting 3x3 array with 3x3 array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 3x3 array called `data`, and a 3x3 array of indices called `idx`. I'd like to be able to use broadcasting to get a new array composed of `data` at the indices given by `idx`. I can approach this naively and do it in a for-loop as in the example below, then compare it to the brute-forced `expected` array:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[0.5, 1.5, 2.5], [0.5, 1.5, 2.5], [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]])
idx = np.array([[0,-1,-2], [1,0,-1], [2,1,0]])
expected = np.array([[0.5, 2.5, 1.5], [1.5, 0.5, 2.5], [2.5, 1.5, 0.5]])

result = np.zeros(np.shape(data))

for i in range(len(idx)):
    for j in range(len(idx[i])):
        result[i,j]=data[i, idx[i,j]]
        
print(expected==result)
# Gives: 3x3 array of True
```

The reason why I am bringing this here, is because I need to apply this to an NxM array, which will take a long time to compute if I apply it as in the example above.

I found two similar questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044036/how-to-properly-broadcast-array-indexing-for-numpy-arrays) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62505046/what-does-numpy-ix-function-do-and-what-is-the-output-used-for)) which are related to my question, but I am not sure how to apply it to an arbitrarily large 2D array. I have attempted the following with no luck:

```
result = data[np.ix_(*idx)] 
# Gives Error: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

and

```
for i in range(len(idx)):
    sub = np.ix_(idx[i])
    print(sub)
    # Gives: (array([ 0, -1, -2]),)
    result[i] = data[sub] 
print(result)
# Gives Error: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)
```

There has to be a way to do this simply with Numpy that I just haven't found.

Comment: The `ix_` links don't apply - `ix_` takes a (n,) array and a (m,) and returns a (n,1) and (1,m) that together broadcast to index (n,m).  You are starting with a (n,m) that you want to index the 2nd axis.  The first axis then needs a (n,1) array, e.g `np.arange(n)[:,None]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that behavior if also explicitly specify the column values

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[0.5, 1.5, 2.5], [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]])
idx = np.array([[0,-1,-2], [1,0,-1]])
expected = np.array([[0.5, 2.5, 1.5], [1.5, 0.5, 2.5]])
print(data[np.arange(len(data)).reshape(-1,1),idx] == expected)
```

Output:

```
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

Comment: This seems to work for NxN arrays, but my specific use case is an NxM array where N<M, so that if I remove one of my rows from the example, I get an error: `indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3)`

Comment: @t.o. Hi, I have adjusted my answer. You will achieve your desired behavior if you reshape the column indices to `(N, 1)`

Comment: I'll have to look into, and practice with `np.reshape(...)`. Thanks for the help!